# My JavaScript doesn't seem to run

Tags: javascript, regex, onload

I'm currently trying to create a regex to work in an input field. The JavaScript itself returns no errors in JS Chrome console, but since onLoad() doesn't even work, I'm very confused. Here is my website if you want to see it yourself:
users.aber.ac.uk/mta2/cs25010

```
<script>
        var regEx = new RegExp("[0-9]+\.[0-9][0-9]");
        var regEx2 = new RegExp("[0-9]+");
        function validateFilter()
        {
            var input = document.forms["filterPrice"]["price"].value;
            if(regEx.test(input) == true || regEx2.test(input) == true)
            {
                alert("Input must be only numbers. Decimal allowed");
                return false;
            }
        }

        function onLoad()
        {
            alert("HI");
        }
    </script>

<form name="filterPrice" action="homepage.php" method="GET" onsubmit="return validateFilter()">
        <select name = priceSelect> 
            <option value = "Greater"> Filter prices greater than </option>
            <option value = "Less"> Filter by prices less than </option>
        </select>
        <input id ="priceInput" name="price" type ="text">  </input>

        <button> Go </button>
</form>
```

Comment: You are not calling `onLoad` anywhere. Just defining it doesn't do much. You also have to "use" it.

Comment: but that still does not explain why my validateFilter() doesn't run..

Comment: True, but you haven't said that it doesn't run. You were just talking about `onLoad`. How do you know that `validateFilter` doesn't run? What happens?

Comment: Try to delete the `return` keyword in the `onClick` attribute

Comment: @Toumash: Why? And which `onClick` attribute?

Comment: Felix, it may run, i dont know.. but it's not doing anything at all

Comment: It's very easy to add an `alert` or `console.log` statement at the beginning of the function and verify that it's at least called.

Comment: Another small point... change `name = priceSelect` to `name="priceSelect"` You should put quotes when defining attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must change if statement to false like this

```
if(regEx.test(input) == false|| regEx2.test(input) == false)
```

Comment: @MaxAtkins: There are more problems with your code, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are not explaining what exactly is wrong with `validateFilter`. But looking at the function and the regular expressions, it's clear that they don't do what you want to do.

If you want to check whether a string contains *only* digits or a decimal like `x.xx` then you your expression should be

```
^\d+(\.\d{2})?$
```

The important part are `^` and `$`. They *anchor* the expression, so the *whole* string must match the pattern, not only *part* of the string. E.g. your expression (`new RegExp("[0-9]+")` also matches `"foo9"` and `"123foobar"`.

The other expression, `new RegExp("[0-9]+\.[0-9][0-9]")`, is also incorrect. It does not just match `0.00` but also e.g. `0x00`. That's because your are using a *string* to define the expression, and `\` is the escape characters for strings as well. So the expression you are creating is actually `[0-9]+.[0-9][0-9]`, where `.` matches any character.

Furthermore, if the expression does *not* match, you want to show the alert, i.e. when `regEx.text(input)` returns `false`, not `true`.

Revised code:

```
var regEx = /^\d+(\.\d{2})?$/;

function validateFilter() {
    var input = document.forms["filterPrice"]["price"].value;
    if (!regEx.test(input)) {
        alert("Input must be only numbers. Decimal allowed");
        return false;
    }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cxfL2qf7/)